# How to check copyright status of livestreaming

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, copyright-display

I'm livestreaming an event and I use some songs from other author. The live video now show the Youtube logo because youtube detect the copyright. The question is can I get the copyright status of video through Youtube API ? So I can stop the song before youtube stop my stream ?

Comment: why do you assume that there's a grace period between reporting any copyright issues via the API and embedding the youtube logo when youtube detects a (purported) copyright infringement? even if you could get the detected copyright status via the API, youtube will also have noticed and publicly flagged the video; so whatever you can do *then* will be too late.

Comment: I understand that, but the purpose is keep the livestream alive. Youtube don't stop the livestream immediately when it detected the copyright music, it leave us sometime to fix it ( I see it in the livestream control room ). Then I think, is there anyway to get the notice by API ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the docs regarding the [**`contentDetails`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos), as stated you can use [**`contentDetails.licensedContent`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.licensedContent) to check if the video is copyrighted:

> Indicates whether the video represents licensed content, which means that the content was uploaded to a channel linked to a YouTube content partner and then claimed by that partner.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank Mr.Rebot . I just checked and `contentDetails.licensedContent ` always return false. Please note that I'm asking about livestreaming, not a VOD video